# GCC, clang disagree with MSVC on narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, narrowing

Consider the following program:

```
struct uint1 {
    unsigned x;
    uint1(unsigned x_) : x(x_) { }
};

struct foo { uint1 a; };

foo f(int v) { 
    return {v}; 
}

struct bar { unsigned a; };

bar g(int v) {
    return {v};
}
```

Now, where do we have narrowing conversions here?

| Compiler | version | narrowing conversion in `f()`? | narrowing conversion in `g()`? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GCC | 11.2 | No | Yes |
| clang | 13.0 | No | Yes |
| MSVC | 19.4 | Yes | Yes |

Which is right? Naively, it seems to me there's a narrowing conversion in both functions.

See it all on <kbd>[GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/858Wbxeqf)</kbd>.

Note: C++17 in case it matters.

Comment: Not all compilers diagnose all issues - and they are not required to. It's on *you*, the programmer, to get everything right according to the standard - if the compiler helps you, that's nice, but not something you can expect or rely on.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `-W` set of command line args for gcc/g++ that control the verbosity of warnings. MSVC has a similar set or command line parameters and VS project settings.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Well, seeing how GCC supposedly diagnoses narrowing conversions, and this is not very complex code, and there are no library differences - GCC should have caught this too. I would think.

Comment: @selbie: I believe I am.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich: You're right, MSVC doesn't just warns you, it declares failure, see clarification. The question stands though...

Comment: Shouldn't uint1 constructor be `explicit uint1(unsigned x_) : x(x_) { }`?

Comment: [dcl.init.list/3.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.7) covers direct initialization (braced initialization) and says "If a narrow conversion is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed." Ill-formed requires a diagnostic.

Comment: But wait, `foo{v}` is a direct initialization of `foo`, not `uint1`. The `v` is (I think) a copy-initialization of `uint1`. That is covered by [over.match.copy](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.copy), which does not declare narrowing conversions ill-formed. So I think msvc is being overly strict here.

Comment: @RaymondChen: How is `v` a copy-initialization of `uint1`? Wouldn't it need to be a `uint1` for that?

Comment: The language formally calls constructing an object implicitly from another object "copy-initialization". It doesn't have to be the same class. You can copy-initialize via conversion. "The initialization that occurs in the `=` form of a brace-or-equal-initializer or condition, as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception, handling an exception, and **aggregate member initialization**, is called [copy-initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#14)."

Answer (score 3):

It seems that GCC and Clang are right in not classing this as a narrowing conversion.

The initialisation in question is that of a `foo` object. Its constructor argument is enclosed in `{}`. There cannot be a narrowing conversion in this initialisation, because the argument of the constructor is not of a numeric type. It is `struct uint1`.

So where does `struct uint1` cone from? It is converted from `v`, but not by means of braced initialisation. The pair of braces around `v` is already occupied by the constructor of `uint1`.

So this is equivalent to `foo{uint1(v)}`.

MSVC on the other hand seems to interpret this as `foo(uint1{v})`, and I don't think this interpretation is justified.

Neither compiler complains about an explicit `foo{uint1(v)}`, as is required by the standard, because there is no narrowing at the top level.

Comment: But doesn't `foo{uint1(v)}` have a narrowing conversion of `v` to `unsigned`?

Comment: It has, but it is not prohibited.

Comment: But isn't the whole point a prohibition of implicit narrowing conversions?

Comment: @einpoklum The whole point of what exactly? Made by whom? Not all narrowing conversions are prohibited, the standard clearly indicates so in many places. `int a; unsigned b; ... a = b; ... b = a;` is not prohibited. It would be suicidal to introduce such prohibition.

Comment: I mean, the whole point of inhibiting any narrowing conversion avoiding making them unintentionally, implicitly? Your examples are rather explicit.

Comment: As a general rule, the language avoids invalidating code that was legal in previous standards. Narrowing conversions in aggregate initialization were permitted in the original C++, so they remain permitted. On the other hand, when a new operation is introduced (such as direct initialization), the new operation can have stricter rules, since there are no previous consumers to break.

Comment: What exactly is explicit in `b = a;`? How is it different from `myfunc(a)` (which remains permitted too)? Explicit type conversions have a name in C++, they are called **casts**.